# How to determine the location of Yii2 console bootstrap file in the runtime?

Tags: yii2

I'm creating a plugin that has a console controller.

Here's the plugin layout

```
plugin/
   controller/
      MyController
```

The content of the controller itself is something like below

```
namespace plugin\controller;

class MyController extends \yii\console\Controller {
     public function actionFoo(){
     }
     public function actionBar(){
     }
}
```

The config of an app that uses that controller will look like this

```
'controllerMap' => [
    'my' => [
        'class' => 'plugin\controller\MyController'
    ]
]
```

That way the app can use something like this for executing the controller

```
yii my/foo
```

The problem is, in the `actionFoo` I want to execute the `actionBar` through `exec()`.

This is as far as I can go,

Since I can set the name of the console command for the controller using the controller map, I can also pass the name as the attribute of the controller.

```
'controllerMap' => [
    'my' => [
        'class' => 'plugin\controller\MyController',
        'name' => 'my',
    ]
]
```

And the controller will be like this

```
namespace plugin\controller;

class MyController extends \yii\console\Controller {

     public $name = 'my';
     public function actionFoo() {
         $yiipath = 'yii';
         $command = PHP_BINARY . " {$yiipath} {$this->my}/bar";
         exec($command);
     }
     public function actionBar() {
     }
}
```

The question is, how do I determine the path of the `yii` script (i.e. Yii console bootstrap file) for the `$yiipath` variable above?

**UPDATE**

The only way I can think of is

```
$yiipath = getcwd()) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $_SERVER['argv'][0];
```

but it's kind of dirty. I'm wondering if there's a cleaner or "Yii2" way?

Comment: Why don't you use $this->actionBar()?

Comment: I'm planning to use a some kind of sandbox to run the actionBar.

Answer (score 1):

U can add to your `yii.php` file:

```
define('YII_EXEC', pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
```

and use in your controller

```
$command = "PHP_BINARY YII_EXEC {$this->my}/bar";
```